# Simple Disk rolling with slipping on a horizontal plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, friction, work, rigid-body-dynamics

This is the first time I've encountered this scenario. I want to understand how to handle it.

Since the disk is slipping, what would be the work done by the frictional force? What is the displacement $dx$ that I need to multiply by the frictional force? What additional information should be given to solve a problem of this form?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find?  It would be helpful if you posted the whole question which you are trying to solve, as given in your textbook.

Comment: Sadly I can't find it in my textbook , but the teacher once whistled the thought of it , it's quite a simple question . Since we know work is force times distance , in the case of no slipping , the static friction does not displace the wheel because of the center of instantaneous velocity principle , but if there was slipping , what would my distance travelled be with respect to the force

Comment: @MikeHarb when there is no slipping the frictional force is zero.

Comment: @Farcher there is static friction when no slipping

Comment: @MikeHarb On the flat if there was a static frictional force acting horizontally this would mean that that frictional force would cause a horizontal acceleration of the centre of mass of the disc.  This does not happen as the disc is rolling at constant velocity so there is no horizontal frictional force.  If the disc was on a slope then there would be a static frictional force.

Comment: Yeah you are right

Answer (score 1):

As drawn the disc's angular speed $\omega$ is too fast as related to the velocity of the centre of mass of the disc $v$ for the no slipping condition ($v = R \omega$, with $R$ the radius of the disc) to be satisfied.

You can think if the frictional force as trying to accelerate the centre of mass whilst at the same time the frictional force applies a torque which is trying to reduce the speed of rotation.

You can evaluate the change in kinetic energy of the disc (translational $\frac 1 2 m v^2$ and rotational $\frac  1 2 I_{cm} \; \omega^2$) before and after the no slipping condition is reached and this is the work done by the disc against the frictional force $F$.
Knowing the constant frictional force (via the coefficient if kinetic friction?) and the work done by the frictional force you can evaluate the displacement of the disc before it stops slipping.

Comment: Yes , its value can be 'indirectly' calculated , but what if we wanted to find the  displacement with respect to the force , what would it be.

Comment: @MikeHarb , I have done a formal derivation and Word writeup for a skidding bowling ball which is closely related to your problem.  Do you want it?

Comment: @DavidWhite yes please

Comment: @MikeHarb , please send a return email address to whited@pearlandisd.org.  I can't easily copy and paste from Word into this medium, but I can send you the whole word document via email.